# Java start multiple commands strictly sequentially

Tags: java, processbuilder, runtime.exec

How can I start multiple commands in a strict sequence (using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` - whatever is simplest)?

**Example:**

```
Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myFirstCommand");
process1.waitFor();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mySecondCommand");
```

works fine, however, I want to call `Runtime.exec/ProcessBuilder.start()` only *once* and *return immediately*. 
So basically it should work as if I called a batch file containing those two commands from a command line tool (what I can't do, because those two commands are generated dynamically).
`mySecondCommand` must not be started before `myFirstCommand` has finished!

Any ideas?

Comment: _None_ of your lines in Example 1 start two commands. Have you read the documentation on those?

Comment: yes, and it works in my code

Comment: The documentation contradicts you. It could "work" in your code only if `myFirstCommand` happened to be such a program which uses its argument as the name of a program to run.

Comment: hm, ok, maybe I misunderstood the documentation. Indeed, the code of the first command could work (differently though), if the seconds command is interpreted as an argument.

Comment: So, what would be the correct way to start two commands. Maybe that's the issue already?

Comment: Your best bet is going platform-specific and delegating this to a shell process. E.g., `exec("sh", "-c", "first_command && second_command");`

Comment: Any chance not to go platform-specific?

Comment: No chance because there is no async API for subprocesses in Java. You'd need an API where you submit an `onProcessDone` callback. But you _can_ sacrifice a thread to do the waiting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Marko. I dropped the first incorrect example from my question.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "correct" example is still broken because you don't consume the standard outputl/errror streams of the subprocess. Stick to `ProcessBuilder#inheritIO`.

Comment: Yeah, the original code snippet is longer anyway (setting directory, env vars) - just wanted to illustrate the actual issue. Thanks anyway for the headsup.

Comment: *"So basically it should work as if I called a batch file containing those two commands from a command line tool (what I can't do, because those two commands are generated dynamically)."*  Write (and execute) a batch file at run time with the data relevant to that moment.  See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Nice and straightforward idea :) Thanks.

Comment: I like that - don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place ;) In fact, now that you are mentioning batch files: I could prepare a (static) batch file and pass in the dynamic part as arguments. I think, that's the way to go in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Batch files need to be called in a shell though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run the second command only if the first command if successful, you can do something like

```
if (process1.exitValue() == 0) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mySecondCommand");
}
```

Comment: The issue to solve is the calling thread going on while the processes execute in background, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

You said "it should work as if I called a batch file containing those two commands from a command line tool". So doing exactly that worked for me:

```
String command = "someComand someParam";
command+= "\nsomeOtherCommand someOtherParam";
String commandname=Utilities.getRandomNameOfLengthLowerCase(10) + ".sh";
command+= "\nrm " + pathToContent + commandname;
Utilities.writeFile(command, pathToContent + commandname);
Process actProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + pathToContent + commandname);
actProcess.waitFor();
actProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToContent + commandname);
```